# Run selenium in vagrant with browser outside virtualmachine

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I'm trying to run selenium in the virtual machine, but when i try she speaks with no there is installed firefox, however I want to point to the browser off the virtual machine. How do this.

I use selenium server and phpunit selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify selenium host when creating webdriver and it goes something like this:

```
RemoteWebDriver::create("http://{$host}:{$port}/wd/hub", $capabilities);
```

The port is `4444` by default.

Now, reaching anywhere from inside the box is a completely different matter, non-related to PHP, PHPUnit or Selenium.

Comment: Thanks for help. I preferred use Selenium in Java